# how to delete the content of a temporary table in SAP HANA?

Tags: delete-row, hana, temp-tables

I create a temp table in SAP HANA this way:

```
  create local temporary table #sometable(table definition);
```

however, the delete statement is not supported on this table. i.e calling:

```
 delete from #sometable;
```

will throw an error:

> feature not supported

When using this table within a stored procedure, the content is concatenated with the new data instead of being replaced with it. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

What HANA Revision are you using? On the most recent Revision 68, it works just fine:

```
;drop table #sometable;
create local temporary table #sometable(id integer, str nvarchar(30));

insert into #sometable values (1,'one');
insert into #sometable values (2,'two');
insert into #sometable values (3,'three');

select * from #sometable;  --> returns 3 rows
delete from #sometable;
select * from #sometable;  --> returns 0 rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem recently and found next explanation in [SAP Hana Developer Guide](http://www.saphana.com/docs/DOC-3816):

> You can define the following values for the @Catalog.tableType annotation:
>
> . . .
>
> 3) #GLOBAL_TEMPORARY
>
> Set the scope of the created table. Data in a global temporary table is session-specific; only the owner session of **the global temporary table is allowed to insert/read/truncate the data**. A global temporary table exists for the duration of the session, and data from the global temporary table is automatically dropped when the session is terminated. A global temporary table can be dropped only when the table does not have any records in it.

That means you can clear temporary table using truncate:

```
truncate table #sometable;
```